# Passing variables to awk code block in org-mode

Tags: emacs, awk, org-mode, org-babel

I have a small code block, in Org-Babel, that should depend on some parameters. I've written my code in awk but I didn't succeed using the parameters in my code.

A small (not working) example:

```
#+begin_src awk :var test="value" :results output
BEGIN { print "Test is "test }
#+end_src
```

My parameter is called test and its value is… value. The results is as follows:

```
#+results:
: Test is
```

The variable test seems not to have be defined despite the `:var test="value"`

However when trying other languages than awk (eg. python of sh), it seems ok:

```
#+begin_src python :var test="value" :results output
print "Test is %s"%test
#+end_src

#+results:
: Test is value

#+begin_src sh :var test="value" :results output
echo "Test is "$test
#+end_src

#+results:
: Test is value
```

I'm using org 7.8.02. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess here, did you try $test?

Comment: Nice try! No I didn't. But that doesn't work either

Comment: Aww… A quick look at [ob-awk.el](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/plain/lisp/ob-awk.el) while searching :var leads me to this… (`(replace-regexp-in-string … (format "$%s" …)…)`). Is `#+begin_src sh :var test="value" :results output` and then `awk '{BEGIN { print "Test is "$test }}'` ok? (not really a solution though…

Comment: Yes using a sh code block would work. But actually you were right in your first comment. However I needed to put $test inside the quotes not outside. So, this works: `BEGIN { print "Test is $test" }`

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine for me with the current org-mode version. I guess this was just a bug back in 2014 in the awk org-babel implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In a UNIX shell you have the following:

```
> VAR="value123"
> echo "Value is $VAR"
value123
```

with awk you have to parse variables with the "-v" option. Otherwise awk won't know your variables inside of awk.

```
> awk -v VARAWK=$VAR 'BEGIN { print "Value is "VARAWK }'
Value is value123
```

Comment: I'm aware of the -v option in awk but my awk code is written in a org-babel code block, meaning that org-babel encapsulates it in a temporary file which is run using awk. My guess was that org-babel should give the -v test=value option to awk. But it seems not to do so. And I'm wondering why.